# Call AppLocalizations’ method through regex

Tags: flutter, dart

I’m trying to build an ItemList in flutter that would call the AppLocalizations.of(context) with the methods value01, value02, value03.

```json
Example of arbFile:
{
  'value01': 'foo',
  'value02': 'bar',
  'value03': 'foobar',
  ...
}
```

Of course I would like this to be called through a for loop fashion without having to write all the code.

--

I thought about parsing the original arb file to find parameters matching the "value.." pattern, but I don't know how would I call the functions in the AppLocalizations then :/

Could (1) a reflectable or (2) extending the i10n-generating-code for AppLocalization work ?

Or is another method even more efficient ?
Thx :)

Comment: So far the best I found is to create a python code that reads the app_en.arb file, and generates a dart class that implements a function: String getParamText(String paramName, context) that return an appLocalization field...

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can achieve your desired functionality by modifying `.arb` files. Instead of creating value01,value02 etc. You can just create one value and use some special character to separate it.

arb file

```
  "value": "value1:value2:value3",
```

Now you can get your values as list using `.split()` method

```dart
final values = AppLocalizations.of(context)!.value.split(':');
```

Now, using a for loop should be a problem :)

```dart
for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++)
    Text(values[i])
```

Comment: That would work on small projects, yes. Mine is not huge, but has about 90ish parameters that I might have to parametrize...
I'll keep this solution in mind for the moment.